# Running a script in FreeBSD after boot/reboot

Tags: cron, sh, freebsd, rc

I have a simple script:

```
#!/bin/sh

PROVIDE: test
REQUIRE: LOGIN NETWORKING

. /etc/rc.subr

name="test"
load_rc_config $name

rcvar=test_enable

cd /home/deploy/projects/test
/usr/sbin/daemon -u deploy /usr/local/bin/node /home/deploy/projects/test/server.js

run_rc_command "$1"
```

inside `/usr/local/etc/rc.d`. It is executable. It is registred into /etc/rc.conf

I need it to start after boot/reboot. I managed to do it with Cron using

```
@reboot
```

but it doesn't look legit. What is the proper way to run that script automatically after boot/reboot?

Comment: Probably a supervisor could help you better, for example: https://immortal.run/freebsd/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, there's an article in the official documentation explaining how to write rc scripts: [Practical rc.d scripting in BSD](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/rc-scripting/).

It will probably answer most of your questions.

When it comes to your script:

1. The keywords like `PROVIDE`, `REQUIRE`, etc. have to be comments. See the [rc(8) manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rc&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+11.2-RELEASE+and+Ports) and the [rcorder(8) manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rcorder&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) for more details.

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   #
   # PROVIDE: test
   # REQUIRE: LOGIN NETWORKING
   ```
2. I think you also miss setting `test_enable` to a default value.

   ```
   : "${test_enable:="NO"}"
   ```
3. You don't really want to just put the instructions to start your daemon in the global scope of the script. This part of your code is bad:

   ```
   cd /home/deploy/projects/test
   /usr/sbin/daemon -u deploy /usr/local/bin/node /home/deploy/projects/test/server.js
   ```

   You should try to define a `start_cmd` function (look for `argument_cmd` in the [rc.subr(8) manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rc.subr&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+11.2-RELEASE+and+Ports) for more information) or define the `command` variable.

---

All in all, the best idea is to look at other scripts in `/etc/rc.d` and `/usr/local/etc/rc.d` to see how people write those and what are the standards. This is how I've learnt it recently as I was developing a daemon for the Keybase filesystem (KBFS). You may look at the code [here](https://github.com/0mp/kbfsd/blob/master/kbfsd.in).

The manpages are also helpful. Start with [rc(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rc&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+11.2-RELEASE+and+Ports) and then look at other manuals listed in the *SEE ALSO* section.

Comment: @Pachvarsh: You might want to take a look at the example in [How to debug rc.d scripts in freeBSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833364/how-to-debug-rc-d-scripts-in-freebsd/51838663#51838663)