# What is neccesary to daemonize a python script?

Tags: python, freebsd, python-daemon

I have a python script that needs to run as a daemon on startup. The process detaches from tty(and pdb), but the code doesn't run.

I've narrowed it down to a minimal example

```py
import daemon
from time import sleep
f1 = open('out.txt','a')
with daemon.DaemonContext():
   while(1):
       f1.write('this is a test')
       sleep(5)
```

I expect the script to keep runiing and adding a line to out.txt every 5 seconds, but the script just detaches from tty(or pdb) and ps -ax shows that the python interpreter isn't running anymore. out.txt is created, but stays empty

Comment: I think a better approach would be to use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to [execute the script](http://supervisord.org/running.html#adding-a-program) instead of using the daemon module

Comment: Please explain what makes you think that @new-dev-123

Comment: You may want to consider using systemd. Take a look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069634/python-daemon-and-systemd-service

Comment: Your operating system already gives you capabilities to run scripts as daemons - most likely one of sysv, upstart or systemd. There is no need to write demonisation yourself.

Comment: The script is to be deployed on FreeBSD, so systemd isn't an option, unfortunately. I've gotten it to show up in ps, but it still doesn't print to the file.

Comment: @p0te: `it doesn't print to the file` because it's buffered. Put `f1.flush()` after `f1.write ...` to see the content of the file immediately.

Comment: @p0te: FWIW, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833364/how-to-debug-rc-d-scripts-in-freebsd/) is a simple example of how to use rc.d.

Comment: @Vladimir Botka thanks, that fixed the printing

Comment: So is your problem solved, or are you getting printing now but then the process is still dying?  I agree with the others in saying that you are best off not having your Python script know anything about how it will run, and using a standard mechanism for running daemon processes, like systemd or supervisord.

Comment: The problem is solved, thanks. The issue was an error that caused the program(not this minimal example) to die in the while(1).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a [process supervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_supervision).

To simplify the process and have a portable solution not depending for example on  `systemd` (Linux only) you could install for example [immortal](https://immortal.run/freebsd/), in FreeBSD just need to do:

```
pkg install immortal
```

Then create a `your-script.yml` with something like this:

```
cmd: sleep 3
```

And daemonize it with:

```
$ immortal -c test.yml
```

To check the status you could use [immortalctl](https://immortal.run/post/immortaldir/):

```
$ immortalctl    
  PID     Up   Down   Name      CMD
29993   0.0s          test   sleep 3
```

If want to have it always up even when rebooting, just move your script (in FreeBSD) to `/usr/local/etc/immortal/your-script.yml`, check more about [immortaldir](https://immortal.run/post/immortaldir/)

You can add more option for exaple:

```
cmd: iostat 3
log:
    file: /tmp/iostat.log
    age: 10  # seconds
    num: 7   # int
    size: 1  # MegaBytes
require_cmd: test -f /tmp/foo
```

For more examples check: https://immortal.run/post/run.yml/